# Azure Databricks Dynamic SQL Stored Proc to Python Notebook

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks, dynamic-sql

I deal with creating tables and views to be used in reports for all our companies’ clients. Each client has their own preferred way to calculate certain metrics, i.e. business rules. The business rules for each client are currently hardcoded throughout our entire codebase, with no central repository or documentation for them. It has caused a lot of headaches when a change request comes through, or when the client tries to reconcile their data with ours.

My solution was to create a table to store the client id, the metric, SQL that defines that metric for that client, metric version, implementation date, and the business user who provided us with the logic. Then in a stored procedure, dynamically replace the parameters for the view creation based on which client is passed to it. To top it off I built a dashboard on top of the table so all client managers could have visibility into how each of their client’s metrics are being calculated.

This system came together well, and it didn’t cause as large of a hit to processing time as initially thought. Now I got word to start planning the move to Azure Databricks , with hopes of eventually decommissioning the on prem SQL servers. I am super excited about this move however, since Databricks doesn’t currently support dynamic SQL I will likely have to develop something in python. Most of the developers in the company work solely with SQL, so I need a solution that will work as a step in a mostly SQL workflow. (Calling a python notebook in a cell of SQL notebook?).

Has anyone had to deal with anything like this before? One of my fears is that I end up developing a complex and convoluted system that slows developer workflow and falls into disuse. I need it to be easy for developers to add, alter, and deactivate business rules.